# Is there a typescript operator that will set an object's property ONLY if some condition is met?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two Typescript objects `x` and `y` as defined below:

```
let x = {A: 1, B: 2};
console.log('x = ', x);
let y = {A: 1};
console.log('y = ', y);

> x = {"A": 1, "B": 2} 
> y = {"A": 1}
```

Now I want to set `y.B` to `x.B` iff `x.B` exists.
And I want to set `y.C` to `x.C` iff `x.C` exists.

Is there an operator I can use to achieve this? Currently I do this, but it seems clunky:

```
if (x.hasOwnProperty('B') && x.B !== null) {
    y.B = x.B;
}
if (x.hasOwnProperty('C') && x.C !== null) {
    y.C = x.C;
}
```

Comment: What's with the null check? Is the type of `x.B` nullable? Also, "typescript operator"? I think this has more to do with JavaScript.

Comment: Will `Object.assign(x, y)` do or do you need individual properties?

Comment: "*Currently I do this, but it seems clunky*" make a function to reduce the code then? `setIfNotNull(x, y, "B")` is not as clunky. And if you want to write less when you have repetitive things then *reusing code* seems like the right approach. Rather than try to figure out which construct lets you still repeat code.

Comment: You can’t do exactly this without using an `if`, in case thats what you consider ‘clunky'.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases your code is equivalent of

```
y.B = x.B ?? y.B;
y.C = x.C ?? y.C;
```

(except if x prototype has B or if x.B is `undefined`)

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly sure about what you want to do but maybe this is the case for the [Optional Chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`?.`).

It can be used like this:

```js
if (x?.B !== null) {
    y.B = x.B;
}
if (x?.C !== null) {
    y.C = x.C;
}
```

<strike>This operator checks for the existence of that property before accessing it.</strike> It accesses the `x.C` and evaluates the expression to `undefined` if it throws an error (instead of throwing the error).

Comment: Why would `x` be nullable here? In the example in the question, the code confidently uses `x.hasOwnProperty()` which wouldn't make sense if `x` was nullable.

Comment: "*This operator checks for the existence of that property before accessing it.*" no? You even link to the documentation for optional chaining. That's not what it does. It checks *the previous item* for nullisness. `a?.b` - will access `a.b` if `a` is not `null` or `undefined`. `a?.b?.c` will access `a.b.c` if both `a` and `a.b` are not `null` or `undefined`. Optional chaining will not check the final accessed property. And if it worked that way, what exactly would be the point? What would you get for `const a = {}; console.log(a?.b)` if when the property doesn't exist before the access?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I really think my answer is a possible solution for OP. I'm not judging the code, just trying to answer OP. To address your other comments, you probably got wrong what Optional Chaining is doing too: **It WILL try to access the final property**. `a?.b` will try to access `a.b` and if `a.b` is not `null` or `undefined` (which throws an error without using it) it'll short-circuit to `undefined` and prevent the error. For your final question, the `console.log(a?.b)` will log `undefined`. Try `console.log(a.b.c)` and `console.log(a.b?.c)`.